# Neo4j - How to find Nodes over multiple opposing Relationships?

Tags: neo4j

im a beginner to Neo4j and im struggling with a task where i have to find nodes over multiple opposing relationships.

The graph model looks like this:
[Graphmodel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/msWQe.png)

I need to list all lines within a segment.
The output should return 3 nodes:

Trainstop1, Trainstop2, Line(-s)

e.g.:

- 10315, 10296, 1026
- ...

Im thankful for all hints :-)

Answer (score 0):

Welcome as a new Neo4j user! I'm making a few assumptions in writing this becasuse you've not fully described the problem. You should consider a different design to your schema. Your ProjSegA ,B, etc. could be a relationship ProjSeg with a property Name, where name is A, B, etc. You might have one type of Line node with property type where type=mainline, subline, etc. You can still have a relationship between the mainline and subline. This schema will make the traversals easier.

```
match p=(l:Line{type:'mainline'})-[r:ProjSeg{name:'A'}*0..x}]->(s:Section) return p
```

Are the Segments related to the lines?

If you clarify the problem, we might give a more cogent reply. But hopefully this provides some clues.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get dead-end nodes from 'Abschnitt' node...

```
match path=(a:Abschnitt)-[r:*1..]->(x)
return last(nodes(path))
```

OR

```
match path=(a:Abschnitt{Section:2})-[r:*1..]->(x) where x:Haltestelle OR x:Linie
with collect(distinct last(nodes(path))) as deadends
with [i in deadends where head(labels(i)) = 'Haltestelle'] as Haltestelle,
     [i in deadends where head(labels(i)) = 'Linie'] as Linie
return Haltestelle.Trainstop, Linie.Line
```